# Keep getting W Invalid DNSEC TXT record signature error in CLI

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, security

So basically, everytime i sync in monderoD cli i get this as the first message after synchronization completes:

***2023-08-28 ??    W Invalid DNSSEC TXT record signature for checkpoints.moneropulse.se: validation failure <checkpoints.moneropulse.se. TXT IN>: no signatures from 80.67.169.40 for DS se. while building chain of trust***

when i tried to simply exit by typing in "exit" on the command line i got "stop signal sent" but it kept repeating the above error.  Then i saw this right after i turned off my wifi and it finally allowed the stop signal to send:

***Stop signal sent
2023-08-28 ??  W Invalid DNSSEC A record signature for seeds.moneroseeds.se: validation failure <seeds.moneroseeds.se. A IN>: no signatures from 80.67.169.40 for DS se. while building chain of trust
2023-08-28 ??  W Invalid DNSSEC A record signature for seeds.moneroseeds.li: validation failure <seeds.moneroseeds.li. A IN>: SERVFAIL no DS for DS li. while building chain of trust
2023-08-28 ??   W Invalid DNSSEC TXT record signature for checkpoints.moneropulse.co: validation failure <checkpoints.moneropulse.co. TXT IN>: SERVFAIL no DS for DS co. while building chain of trust
2023-08-28 ?? W WARNING: no two valid DNS TXT records were received***

i have no idea what is happening can someone please help?  p.s. don't mind the "??" i replaced the numbers with these just to be safe.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> W Invalid

These are just *warning* log messages. As these are all related to DNS, perhaps check you system's DNS settings.

When checkpoints / seed lists are requested from DNS, a bunch of hosts are tried. Patience may be required to try them all.